# Create multiple Web Api with same signature

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a `CAR` controller and create my API to Get a list of cars with detailed information of each car in a `GRID` and work OK.

Now Im creating a `ListTree` for the cars and only need the basic details. `ID and Color`

How I create another method `GetSimpleCar()` with same signature in current controller or should I create another controller `CarSimple`

Current I have:

```
public List<dtoCar> Get()
{
   List<dtoCar> result = db.cars.Select(
                                 r => new dtoCar
                                 {
                                   Car_ID = r.car_id,
                                   X = r.x,
                                   Y = r.y,
                                   RoadName = r.rto.name,
                                   Azimuth = (int)r.avl.azimuth,
                                   Color = r.Color,
                                   DateTime = r.datetime.Value, 
                                   Geom = r.geomtext
                                 }).ToList();
   return result;
}
```

I dont want use the current API to create the Tree.

```
$('#ajax').jstree({
    'core': {
        'data': {
         -- RIGHT NOW
            "url": "http://localhost/TreeTest/api/Cars/"
                                                  ^^   
                                                 Controller
         -- DESIRE CHANGE
            "url": "http://localhost/TreeTest/api/Cars/GetSimpleCar"
                                                            ^^ 
                                                       Second Method?
        } 
    },
    "checkbox": {
        "keep_selected_style": false
    },
    "plugins": ["wholerow", "checkbox"]
});
```

Comment: Your labels are wrong, since your route is /api... it seems to me you are using WebAPI controllers not MVC !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a fixed route in the same controller like this:

```
using System.Web.Http;
...    
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Cars/GetSimpleCar")]
public object GetCarsButOnlyIdAndColor()
{
    return db.cars.Select(r => new
    {
        Car_ID = r.car_id,
        Color = r.Color,
    }).ToList();
}
```

WebApi doesn't care about the method's name, it's the route that matters.

And like vendettamit  said, you will need to [Enable Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#enable)

Documentation:

[Routing and Action Selection in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection)

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: This sound like the way I want. And my desire `URL` would be OK?

Comment: Yes, I added a link to my answer that explains how WebAPI goes from your url to a method in the controller.

Comment: Yes, I did a fast reading, but saw something to change the `routes.MapHttpRoute` ? or with only the `[Route(" ")]` will be ok?

Comment: You can use either one, it's up to you and what you prefer. Personally I find attribute routing (`[Route(" ")]`) simpler.

Comment: Sound like the right solution but the route property doesnt work for me. Trying to see what is wrong, but that would be a different question.

Comment: Don't forget to enable the AttributeRouting.  `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` in WebApiConfig.

Comment: And ensure you are using the correct namespace. WebAPI attribute is `[System.Web.Http.Route()]`